# Kendo UI Grid send all grid data to the server on row update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My application is similar to this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

Would it be possible to send all grid rows data on update to the server? Because now I only send data of the row I'm currently editing. So I would like to make it for example if the grid has 5 rows and if I choose to to edit row #2, all 5 rows data would be sent to the server after I hit update.

I've tried to remove id: `id: "ProductID"`. Then it sends all the grid data to the server, but then "Cancel" button in popup mode works incorrectly (you can read more about the issue: http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-popup-edit-cancel-problem).

Any ides?

Comment: Maybe I should add dirty flag on all grid items?

Comment: Dirty flag might work but you will be sending 5 rows anyway. Where is the 6th in your example? The 5 original ones plus the edited as a different row, is this?

Comment: You should make the dirty flag "true" for the items you need to send back to the server.

Comment: @OnaBai, I have only 5 rows in the grid. 6th row may be new row, that I also would like to send it to the server. The thing is if I create new row, it is sent to the server on different request. One request comes with new row and other request comes with all the rows(but without newly created item) that I set dirty flag.